# How to type this two letters in latex

Tags: symbols, fontspec, characters, letters

[image]

and

[image]

The first one look like `$\xi$` but not completely the same.

Comment: `\xi`? It rather looks like `\mathcal{E}` (and the other one `\mathcal{F}` etc.

Comment: The site [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) can help you find the correct symbols.

Comment: Detexify does suggest `\xi`